# Magento - update the qty invoiced in sales_flat_order_item table

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I need to change the value of the `qty_invoiced` column for certain order in the `sales_flat_order_item` table, but unfortunately nothing happens.

here is my code:

```
$allOrders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete');

foreach ($allOrders as $value) {
  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($value->getId());
  if($order->getincrementId() == '100000003'){
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
      $qtyOrdered = $item->getQtyOrdered();
      $item->setQtyInvoiced($qtyOrdered);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to save the item and the order after setting the new quantity.

```php
foreach ($allOrders as $value) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($value->getId());
    if($order->getincrementId() == '100000003'){
        /** @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item */
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $qtyOrdered = $item->getQtyOrdered();
            $item->setQtyInvoiced($qtyOrdered);
            $item->save();

        }
    }
    $order->save();
}
```